# Filling missing values using forward and backward fill in pandas dataframe (ffill and bfill)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Beginner with panda dataframes. I have this data set below with missing values for column A and B (Test.csv):

```
DateTime              A             B
01-01-2017 03:27        
01-01-2017 03:28        
01-01-2017 03:29    0.18127718  -0.178835737
01-01-2017 03:30    0.186923018 -0.183260853
01-01-2017 03:31        
01-01-2017 03:32        
01-01-2017 03:33    0.18127718  -0.178835737
```

I can use this code to fill in values using forward propagation, but this only fills in for 03:31 and 03:32, and not 03:27 and 03:28.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col = 0)
data = df.fillna(method='ffill')
ndata = data.to_csv('test1.csv')
```

results in:

```
   DateTime              A             B
    01-01-2017 03:27        
    01-01-2017 03:28        
    01-01-2017 03:29    0.18127718  -0.178835737
    01-01-2017 03:30    0.186923018 -0.183260853
    01-01-2017 03:31    0.186923018 -0.183260853
    01-01-2017 03:32    0.186923018 -0.183260853
    01-01-2017 03:33    0.18127718  -0.178835737
```

How could I include the 'Bfill' to fill in the missing values for 03:27 and 03:28 using the backfil?

Comment: did you try `data = df.fillna(method='bfill')`? or even `data = df.bfill()`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and [`bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) if need replace `NaN` values forward and backward filling:

```
print (df)
                         A         B
DateTime                            
01-01-2017 03:27       NaN       NaN
01-01-2017 03:28       NaN       NaN
01-01-2017 03:29  0.181277 -0.178836
01-01-2017 03:30  0.186923 -0.183261
01-01-2017 03:31       NaN       NaN
01-01-2017 03:32       NaN       NaN
01-01-2017 03:33  0.181277 -0.178836

data = df.ffill().bfill()
print (data)
                         A         B
DateTime                            
01-01-2017 03:27  0.181277 -0.178836
01-01-2017 03:28  0.181277 -0.178836
01-01-2017 03:29  0.181277 -0.178836
01-01-2017 03:30  0.186923 -0.183261
01-01-2017 03:31  0.186923 -0.183261
01-01-2017 03:32  0.186923 -0.183261
01-01-2017 03:33  0.181277 -0.178836
```

Which is same as the function [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with parameters:

```
data = df.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the order by which you call ffill and bfill has to be fit to your use case.