# How to make connect 4 pieces go to the bottom?

Tags: python, list

I'm making a "connect 4" game (basically) and I'm making a list with the "pieces" which are represented by X's and O's, empty space being represented by ".". I'm having trouble making the pieces going to the "bottom" (I'll post console output to be more clear)

example of a completely empty board:

```
   . . . . .
   . . . . .
   . . . . .
   . . . . .
```

Here's my current code:

```
 import random
 a = []
 i = 20

for o in range(0,i+1):
    o = random.choice('XO.')
    a.append(o)


 n = 5
 for group in zip(*[iter(a)] * n):
     print(*group)
```

Pretty easy and simple code, and it mostly works how I want it to except for this (for example, each run is different):

```
  . X X . .
  X O . O X
  . . O . X
  X X X . X
```

The issue is that the empty slots have pieces on top of them. So for this example, i would need the output to be more like this:

```
. . . . .       
. X X . X     
X O O . X
X X X O X
```

I'm assuming the problem is me using the random module to place pieces and empty spaces... randomly. But it's also a fairly crucial part of the program I'm making.

How could I tweak this to work?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: First of all, why not use a list of lists? You are representing a 2D structure, after all.

Comment: Just a thought, maybe bfill or ffill, might do the trick for you. You can see about what they are in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589365/filling-missing-values-using-forward-and-backward-fill-in-pandas-dataframe-ffil ... The only issue is... How to use it iteratively. I could've helped you myself, but using my phone to answer you right now. Give it a try... Maybe you can get it on your own.

Comment: I'm all for lists of lists if that's the solution

Comment: This can't be solved by just randomly placing pieces on the board. You will need to know what column a piece is being dropped in, and then iterate up the rows until finding the first empty slot. Try drawing a grid on paper or a whiteboard and figure out how you will traverse through each cell.

Comment: With your current code in addition to the pieces hovering, you also have another problem with players not necessarily having the same number of turns depending on the luck of the draw - don't know if this is an issue, just figured I'd point it out.

Comment: @norlesh the program is not meant to be for player use as silly as that sounds on paper, it's supposed to only be used to display boards. Thank you though (Y)

Comment: @LandonG Is a list of tuples fine?

Comment: @Tomothy32 you bet man. Anything that will get the solution I'm fine with. I'm not picky!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in one line:

```
import random

width = 5
height = 4

board = list(zip(*[sorted([random.choice('XO.') for _ in range(height)], key=lambda x: x != '.') for _ in range(width)]))
```

A sample board:

```
[('.', '.', '.', '.', '.'),
 ('X', '.', '.', 'O', 'O'),
 ('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O'),
 ('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')]
```

Explanation: First, I generate columns randomly and shift the `.`'s to the front with `sorted([random.choice('XO.') for _ in range(width)], key=lambda x: x != '.')`. I repeat that action with `for _ in range(height)`, yielding me a horizontal board. I then `list(zip(*))` it to make it upright.

---

To print the board:

```
for row in board:
    print(*row)
```

to get

```
. . . . .
X . . O O
X O X O O
X X X O O
```

Comment: Do I add this to the current program or is this the whole program? Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: You can replace all of your code with it. I will add how to print it.

Comment: Even without `key=lambda x: x != '.'` you can have the desired OP output. But still a neat answer.

Comment: @ChihebNexus It's true the `.`'s would be moved to the front because of ASCII values, but unfortunately the `X`'s and `O`'s would also be sorted, taking away from the randomness.