# How to fill 0 values in dataframe from right to left?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I know there are `fillna` and `ffill` that can be used to fill values in data frame from bottom to top. Is there any method to do this from right to left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [bfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) do the job for you?

With a relevant [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589365/filling-missing-values-using-forward-and-backward-fill-in-pandas-dataframe-ffil).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a beginner in python. all functions are very unfamiliar to me..

Comment: No worries! Glad it helped you out! Welcome to stackoverflow!